# How to perform multi-step ahead in MLP time series model?

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, prediction

[This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10162/how-to-apply-neural-network-to-time-series-forecasting) explained steps to building time series model for forecasting. However, the model is used for one-step ahead. How can I perform multi-step ahead?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert on MLP time series models, but logically there are two ways you can do this. These examples asume you want to skip 2 steps, and the trainingset is `x1, x2, x3, xn...`

**Method 1, teach to skip months:**

You should train your network as follows:

`Input: [x1, x2, x3], Output: [x6]`

You basically just teach it the pattern between `xn, xn+1, xn+2` and `xn+5`.

**Method 2, predict multiple months**

This advise is more eye-appealing, but it requires more steps:

`Input: [x1, x2, x3], Output: [x4]` -> save `x4` to next step

`Input: [x2, x3, x4], Output: [x5]` -> save `x5` to next step

`Input: [x3, x4, x5], Output: [x6]` -> you have your output