# Recurrent neural networks in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, neural-networks

I've heard a bit about using [neural networks to forecast time series](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9842/getting-started-with-neural-networks-for-forecasting), specifically [recurrent neural networks](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8000/proper-way-of-using-recurrent-neural-network-for-time-series-analysis).

I was wondering, is there a recurrent neural network package for R?  I can't seem to find one on [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/TimeSeries.html).  The closest I've come is the [nnetTs](http://www.oga-lab.net/RGM2/func.php?rd_id=tsDyn:nnet) function in the [tsDyn](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tsDyn/index.html) package, but that just calls the [nnet](http://www.oga-lab.net/RGM2/func.php?rd_id=nnet:nnet) function from the [nnet](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nnet/index.html) package.  There's nothing special or "reccurant" about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is the RSNNS package that provides access to the "Stuttgart Neural Network Simulator" (SNNS). It contains the classical recurrent network structures of types 'Jordan' and 'Elman'. SNNS is a bit old (before 2000), but may still be worth a try. The R package itself has been updated in September this year.

Answer (score 3):

I am hoping someone with more R knowledge than me will submit an R answer, but I am not aware of anything. Here is one option: Use one of the multiple Python-based implementations (e.g. [PyBrain](http://pybrain.org/docs/tutorial/netmodcon.html?highlight=recurrent) or [PyNeurGen](http://pyneurgen.sourceforge.net/recurrent.html)) and interface back to R via Rpy or (my prefence) [pyRserve](http://packages.python.org/pyRserve/). I know this is not ideal, but it could given you an easier way forward than writing your own package, at least at first. Also, I am guessing it would be preferable to call Python from R, but I don't think the [RSPython](http://www.omegahat.org/RSPython/) package in R has been updated for some time.

EDIT: It looks like PyNeurGen may not have been updated in some time either. PyBrain seems to have the largest following and is under [active development](https://github.com/pybrain/pybrain).

Answer (score 1):

There is a new package out: rnn (on [CRAN](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=rnn), on [github](https://github.com/bquast/rnn)), which implements a recurrent neural network in native R code.

A nice example can be found here: 
http://firsttimeprogrammer.blogspot.de/2016/08/plain-vanilla-recurrent-neural-networks.html