# Difference between particle filter (PF) and recurrent neural network (RNN) for time series

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, state-space-models, particle-filter

Both method are used to estimate time series from data. The question is, when should I use one method or other? Is any advantage to use one instead of the other?

I know that in a PF there is a hidden model with statistic significance, and for an RNN there is no need for a model (please tell me if I'm wrong), just training data.

I've found some clues [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8000/proper-way-of-using-recurrent-neural-network-for-time-series-analysis?lq=1#comment41424_8014)

Comment: Maybe the author of the "clue", @bayerj , can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

PF is an optimization technique, think things like gradient descent, where RNN is the model the optimization technique is applied to.
TLDR:
PF is a technique for optimizing a set of parameters using bayes theorem.
RNN is a level of abstraction to NN (allowing cyclical connections). These cyclical connections make it difficult to train properly using gradient decent with back propagation. This has led to alternative RNN structures such as lstm or alternative optimization such as backpropagation through time.
PF-RNN are just the optimization schema of a PF applied to an RNN.